# Angular ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get a value from my form, but I keep getting this error. This is the code. My formControlName is 'name' for the value, and I am trying to put it in a variable of type Address, a class I created. The variable is newAddress, and the form group is addressForm. Here is the function in which I am trying to implement it, and here is my Address class.

```
onSubmit() {
    this.newAddress.name = this.addressForm.value['name'];
    console.log(this.newAddress.name);
    this.addressForm.reset({
      name: '',
      addressLine1: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
      zipcode: '',
     });
      this.addressFormDirective.resetForm();
  }
```

```
export class Address {
    name: string;
    addressLine1: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    zipcode: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly initialize it in  constructor like

```
this.newAddress=new Address()
```